# DevOps registration script error: Current() ).IsInRole(...)

Tags: azure, iis, deployment, devops, vps

I can't get my registration script to run in PowerShell (admin). It works in Powershell ISE, but then the script is stuck at "Connecting to the server..."

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

This is the script:

```
 $ErrorActionPreference="Stop";If(-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)){ throw "Run command in an administrator PowerShell prompt"};If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt (New-Object System.Version("3.0"))){ throw "The minimum version of Windows PowerShell that is required by the script (3.0) does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell." };If(-NOT (Test-Path $env:SystemDrive\'azagent')){mkdir $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'}; cd $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'; for($i=1; $i -lt 100; $i++){$destFolder="A"+$i.ToString();if(-NOT (Test-Path ($destFolder))){mkdir $destFolder;cd $destFolder;break;}}; $agentZip="$PWD\agent.zip";$DefaultProxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$securityProtocol=@();$securityProtocol+=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol;$securityProtocol+=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=$securityProtocol;$WebClient=New-Object Net.WebClient; $Uri='[url]';if($DefaultProxy -and (-not $DefaultProxy.IsBypassed($Uri))){$WebClient.Proxy= New-Object Net.WebProxy($DefaultProxy.GetProxy($Uri).OriginalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory( $agentZip, "$PWD");.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "Production" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url '[devopsUrl]' --projectname 'Storms' --auth PAT --token [token]; Remove-Item $agentZip;
```

Comment: It might be a permissions issue, did you try to test it as admin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quotation marks are the issue. There are multiple types of quotation marks and depending on your country of residence this can cause issues.

This can be solved by removing the quotation marks around "Administrator" and adding them back manualy.

You can see the difference here:
“Administrator” versus "administrator"

Notice the difference in the quotation marks? The first pair is american and the second is the european version.

Comment: This was my problem, Administrator had non ascii quotes around it.  Once I changed those to regular quotes and re-pasted into PS, the script ran without issue.

Comment: Incredible that this is the solution!

Answer (score -1):

***To resolve the above issue we need to run the script on Windows PowerShell (Run as Administrator)***

[image]

For more information Please refer the below links:

- Blog:- [***DevOps Deployment Group script stuck on “Connecting to the server.***](https://www.myerrorsandmysolutions.com/devops-deployment-group-script-stuck-on-connecting-to-the-server/)
- Blog:- [***Getting started with Azure DevOps -create a deployment group***](https://skundunotes.com/2019/12/27/azure-devops-deployment-groups/)

Comment: I run my powershell as admin, but it is not working...

Comment: May i know Which `powershell`version do you have .

Comment: Version 5.1.20348.320

Comment: Could you please restart your `powershell` and try to run it again with same ,If not.

Comment: When you copy the script ,have you checked the personal token access as per this [Image](https://imgur.com/XuzJK5a)

Comment: Still same error... I can run the script in PowerShell ISO but then it is stuck at "Connecting to server"

Comment: Could you please try to run in regular powershell window without using ISO.

Comment: And also please check the  above image ,Have you selected or not.

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear:

1. Yes I have checked the personal token access
2. I get the errors when I run it in the regular PowerShell, but when I run it in the ISO it works... but it doesn't connect to the server. So that is not a solution.

Comment: I've added the solution below.